# If Statement to detect certain words in a string

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to write a java program that detects specific words in a string, deemed "profane words". The user enters a string and the program should print to screen that profane words were detected for it should print that no profane words are detected. For this program the profane words are "cat", "dog", and "llama". The program should detect these words if they are capitalized. It should not identify words as profane that include the profane words. Ex: cats or catatonic are not profane.

I've written a program that runs and detects the profane words accordingly. However, it prints to the screen both "Profane word(s) detected" and "No profane words detected". I'm struggling to figure out how to just get it to print profane words detected when their is in fact a profane word.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ch3_Programming_Project3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean startProgram=true; 

        System.out.println("The words cat, dog, and llama are considered"
                  +" profane and will not be allowed.");

        if (startProgram== true) {

            System.out.println("Please enter a sentence:");
            String sentence=keyboard.next();
            sentence=sentence.toLowerCase();

            boolean cat=true, dog=true, llama=true;

            if (sentence.contains("cat")) {
                cat=true;
            }

            if (sentence.contains("dog")) {
                dog=true;
            }

            if (sentence.contains("llama")) {
                llama=true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("No profanity detected." + " Sentence approved.");
            }

            if (cat==true || dog==true || llama==true) {

                if (cat == true) {
                    if (cat==true&&dog==true&&llama==true) {
                        System.out.println("Profanity detected");
                        System.exit(0);
                    } else if (cat==true && dog==true) {
                        System.out.println("Profanity detected");
                        System.exit(0);
                    } else if (cat==true && llama==true) {
                        System.out.println("Profanity detected");
                        System.exit(0);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Profanity detected");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }    
                }

                if (dog == true) {
                    if (dog==true && llama==true) {
                        System.out.println("Profanity detected");
                        System.exit(0);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Profanity detected");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }                     
                }

                if (llama == true) {
                    System.out.println("Profanity detected");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        } else if (startProgram == false) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Program was force closed.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }//end main
}//end class
```

I am very new to java and genuinely want to learn. Yes, this is a homework assignment. But I have already submitted it and am here in an attempt to understand where my mistake is and learn. I've tried googling and searching other posts to identify my problem but have had no success.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Why do you have so many `if/else` branches that do the same thing?

Comment: `firstly` shouldn't `String sentence=keyboard.next();` be `String sentence=keyboard.nextLine();`

Comment: Is your actual code indented like that? It's completely unreadable. Please run it through a prettifier like https://codebeautify.org/javaviewer and edit the question with the formatted code.

Comment: After formatting your code, it is a lot easier to see how you would get "No profanity detected" and then "Profanity detected" - if your string did not contain `llama`. With the sea of if/else statements and no consistent formatting, it is very easy to lose your place. Practice good code hygene. Format and indent your code consistently, and break up code into smaller units with functions, and it will help make your code more readable and bugs easier to spot (and avoid).

Comment: @GBlodgett I think I got to a point of way over thinking this code resulting in the many if/else branches. Having taken a step back a read everyone's suggestions it makes a lot more sense how to consolidate the code and have it be less messy

Comment: @radiodef my actual code is not as unreadable as what's posted here but it definitely isn't as clean as it could be. Thanks for the help and the prettifier link it's very helpful

Comment: @MadsHansen thank you. I've been trying to improve my formatting but clearly this code got away from me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is overly complicated and can be simplified quite a bit.

First of all, all of your `if/else` statements can be reduced down to just one.  Also, as Scary Wombat pointed out in the comments, you should have used `keyboard.nextLine()` to get the input from the user.

Here's the new code for you `Main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("The words cat, dog, and llama are considered"
            + " profane and will not be allowed.");

    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence:");
    String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();
    sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();

    boolean foundProfane = false;
    if (sentence.matches(".*\\bcat\\b.*")
            || sentence.matches(".*\\bdog\\b.*")
            || sentence.matches(".*\\bllama\\b.*")) {
        foundProfane = true;
    }

    if (foundProfane) {
        System.out.println("Profanity Detected!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No profanity detected!");
    }

}
```

The `.*\\b` and `\\b.*` in the strings allow you to capture only the full word, so it will not be flagged when entering "catalog," for example.

With using just one `boolean` to track whether a profane word was added, you can keep all of your checks in one place and just flip the `boolean` if a naughty word is found.

Also, I removed the whole `startProgram` structure, as it had no effect on the program at all.

**Note:** There are several other improvements that could be made but since you are just getting started with Java, this should still be in line with your current skill level. Happy Coding!

Comment: Answer edited to use a regular expression instead of just looking for the string. This will meet your requirement of catching "cat" but not "cats" or "catatonic."

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

You code can be simplified a lot by splitting the sentence and storing the bad words in a `List`

```
    List<String> pwords = Arrays.asList(new String []{"dog", "cat", "llama"});

    String str = "it is raining a cat and a dog";
    // or accept from keyBoard
    //System.out.println("Please enter a sentence:");
    // String str = keyboard.nextLine();
    // str = str.toLowerCase();

    System.out.println(str);
    String [] arr = str.split("\\s+");
    for (String w : arr) {

        if (pwords.contains(w)) {
            System.out.println("contains profanity");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("a clean sentence");
```

**edit**

Output

```
it is raining a cat and a dog
contains profanity

it is raining a cats and a dogs
a clean sentence
```

Comment: maybe use split on any white character     String [] arr = str.split("\\s+");

Comment: @Jai " Ex: cats or catatonic are not profane." that is in the question...

Comment: @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec Yep, fixed

Answer (score 0):

So you start the program by checking to see if a `String` contains the profane words and then have flags to indicate if it contains any profane words. Good approach.

However after this..

If any of the three flags are true: `System.out.println("Profanity detected");
                               System.exit(0);`

If `dog` is true: `System.out.println("Profanity detected");
              System.exit(0);`

If either of the two flags are true: `System.out.println("Profanity detected");
                                      System.exit(0);`

Else: `System.out.println("Profanity detected");
      System.exit(0);`

if `cat` is true: `System.out.println("Profanity detected");
              System.exit(0);`

If either of the other two flags is true: `System.out.println("Profanity detected");
                                    System.exit(0);`

I'm going to stop there but I think you see my point. Basically every single branch in your `if-else` web here leads to the same thing. You need to consolidate it. You could simply do in your first `if-else` branch something like:

```
if(sentence.contains("llama") {
   System.out.println("Contains profane word: llama");
}
//And so on
```

This way you wouldn't even need flags or any other `if-else`'s (Also as pointed out in the other answers you need to change `keyboard.next()` to `keyboard.nextLine()`

Comment: This would still be marked as profane if "catatonic" has been entered...

Comment: @Zephyr True, I was just giving an example of how the OP could simplify his program